# Unable to inject service into service for testing purposes

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have an angular service which inects `appConfigService` as a dependency.

```
@Injectable()
export class UrlService {
    constructor(
        private appConfigService: AppConfigService,
        @Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window,
        @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private defaultAppConfig: AppConfig
    ) {
    }


    public getResource(resource: string): string {
        return this.appConfigService.config;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to override the usage of `AppConfigService` in my test so I can get it to return something specific. I have it setup like so where it gets added as a provider in the `configureTestingModule` providers array.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            UrlService,
            { provide: AppConfigService, useValue: MOCK_APP_CONFIG_SERVICE },
            { provide: WINDOW, useValue: MOCK_WINDOW },
            { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: CONFIG },
        ]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(UrlService);
});

afterEach(() => {
    service = null;
});

it('gets the mocked resource', () => {
    expect(service.getResource('')).toBe(EXPECTED_VALUE);
});
```

This is what `MOCK_CONFIG_SERVICE` looks like:

```
export const MOCK_APP_CONFIG_SERVICE = {
    get config() { return CONFIG; }
};
```

The problem I'm having is that it doesn't seem to be injecting correctly. This test was working on version 7 but has since decided to fail after moving to Angular 10. Did something change with how this works? I'm currently using Angular `10.1.6`. I'm also using karma-jasmine version 4.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `service = TestBed.get(UrlService);` with `service = TestBed.inject(UrlService);` The get function was deprecated. They aren't identical but in most cases you can just swap them out.

Comment: Doesn't change it sadly

Answer (score 0):

Most working examples of the behavior you want, that  I’ve seen also call createComponent(). I’m not sure about everything that happens under the hood but Missing that method call might be causing angular to create a component for you in its default way (so with the real service  dependency) instead of the one you’re trying to configure with a mocked dependency from within your test.